# How to match question mark inside uri in enginx and redirect 301 to another url

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

We prepared to migrate from old software to new one. We need redirect some old, stored in google links to one locations.

I trying to redirect a links http://domain/?start=1432 to http://domain/ (or `/index.php` , or `/category`, whatever else).

I know, that "?" mark in **nginx**, cannot comment like '`/?`'. I have tried use variable `$query_string` or `$args`, or `$is_args $args`, but without effect.

this is part of my conf:

```
location / {
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args; # it's nessesary to execute the php app running on this host.
}

if $request_uri ~ ^\?start=[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] {
 return 301 $scheme://new.domain/;
}
```

also try rewrite to / or `/index.php`, but whitout effect... can anyone to help?

Comment: You are missing parentheses and the leading `/`. Try: `if ( $request_uri ~ ^/\?start=[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$ ) { return ...; }`

Comment: Wonderful, it works ;) Thanks!